# Typedef compilation error on function overload

Tags: c++, overloading, typedef

Why can't I compile the program 1 when the the program 2 is working fine ? Why is it's behavior different?

Program 1:

```
#include <iostream>
typedef int s1;
typedef int s2;

void print(s1 a){ std::cout << "s1\n"; }
void print(s2 a){ std::cout << "s2\n"; }

int main() {
        s1 a;
        s2 b;

        print(a);
        print(b);

        return 0;
}
```

Program 2:

```
#include <iostream>
typedef struct{int a;} s1;
typedef struct{int a;} s2;

void print(s1 a){ std::cout << "s1\n"; }
void print(s2 a){ std::cout << "s2\n"; }
int main() {
        s1 a;
        s2 b;

        print(a);
        print(b);

        return 0;
}
```

This is a bug reproduce from templated class, How can I verify if two template argument are from the same type (in the case of the program 1)

Comment: `typedef` doesn't create new types.  `struct` does.  So `s1` and `s2` are of two different types in your second code, but not so in the first.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need the typedef around structs and classes, in C++.

Comment: @GMan - you don't need the typedef if you write '`struct s1 { int a; };`'.  However, when you omit the structure tag as shown, you do need the typedef to give it a name.  (No typedef and you define a variable of the anonymous struct type - at least in C.)

Comment: @Jonathan: I meant he'd therefore move the name to the front. But it was probably for the question at hand anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typedefs don't define new types, they merely create aliases for existing types. In your first program `s1` and `s2` are both aliases for `int`. In your second program they are aliases for two different structures that just happen to be identical in structure.

You could have assigned names to the two structures which would have made this clearer:

```
// Semantically identical to program 2
typedef struct a {int a;} s1;
typedef struct b {int a;} s2;
```

On the other hand if you made them aliases for the *same* type then the second program would fail just like the first:

```
// Different from program 2. This will draw a compile error.
struct s {int a;};
typedef struct s s1;
typedef struct s s2;
```

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a primitive type: no matter where you use it, it will always refer to *exactly* the same thing - an `int`.

`struct{int a;}` is not a primitive type - each time you define a `struct{int a;}`, you're creating a new type - hence why `s1` and `s2` are considered distinct in your Program 2 case.

For instance, consider the following:

```
typedef struct{int count;} apples;
typedef struct{int count;} airplanes;
```

Are apples and airplanes the same thing? Probably not. But their counts are both numerical counts. Hence why `int` is consistent but `structs` are not - `int` has no context associated with it, structs do.

`typedef` doesn't actually make any new types - it only aliases a type under another name.

Therefore, the difference between Program 1 and Program 2 is that in Program 1, you're attempting to define two versions of a function with (as far as the compiler is concerned) exactly the same signature: `print(int)`. In Program 2, you're defining two different signatures: `print([first struct type])` and `print([second struct type])`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in program 1, `s1` and `s2` are aliases of the same type, whereas in program 2 they're different types.  You can't define two overloads of a function with the same signature, even if you use different type names to produce that signature.